# How do I concatenate initial css/js files create by webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

Here is my webpack base config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const fs = require('fs');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const AddAssetHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('add-asset-html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
// const PreloadWebpackPlugin = require('preload-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');

const root = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');
const dll = path.resolve(root, 'dll');
const src = path.resolve(root, 'src');
var entry = path.resolve(src, 'entry');
var dist = path.resolve(root, 'dist');
const template = path.resolve(root, 'public/index.html');

const plugins = [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template,
        title: 'xxx',
        filename: 'index.html',
        minify: {
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeComments: true,
            useShortDoctype: true,
            minifyCSS: true,
            minifyJS: true,
            removeEmptyElements: true
        }
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        NEED_LOADING: true
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from: './public/fsscConfig.js',
            to: './'
        },
        {
            from: './public/html2canvas.min.js',
            to: './'
        },
        {
            from: './public/promisePolyfill.js',
            to: './'
        },
        {
            from: './public/CryptoKit.YYRL.x64.cab',
            to: './'
        },
        {
            from: './public/CryptoKit.YYRL.x86.cab',
            to: './'
        }
    ]),
    new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
        defer: 'iconfont'
    }),
    // new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
    //     rel: 'prefetch',
    //     as: 'script',
    //     include: 'asyncChunks'
    // }),
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
];
const files = fs.readdirSync(dll);
if (files && files.length) {
    files.forEach((file) => {
        if (/.*\.dll.*.js/.test(file)) {
            plugins.push(
                new AddAssetHtmlWebpackPlugin({
                    publicPath: 'js',
                    outputPath: 'js',
                    filepath: path.resolve(dll, file)
                })
            );
        }
        if (/.*\.manifest.json/.test(file)) {
            plugins.push(
                new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                    manifest: path.resolve(dll, file)
                })
            );
        }
    });
}

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: ['babel-polyfill', entry]
    },
    output: {
        path: dist
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.less', '.scss', '.css', '.json', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'],
        alias: {
            '@': src,
            '@utils': path.resolve(src, 'utils'),
            '@common': path.resolve(src, 'common'),
            '@config': path.resolve(src, 'config'),
            '@style': path.resolve(src, 'style'),
            '@libs': path.resolve(src, 'libs'),
            '@imgs': path.resolve(src, 'imgs'),
            '@platform': path.resolve(src, 'platform'),
            '@custom': path.resolve(src, 'custom'),
            '@app': path.resolve(src, 'app'),
            '@ant-design/icons/lib/dist$': path.resolve(src, 'style/antdIcon')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: src,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory'
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|svg|ttf|woff2|gif|appcache)(\?|$)/,
                exclude: /^node_modules$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]',
                include: src
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                // exclude: /^node_modules$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=images/[hash:8].[name].[ext]'
                // include: [SRC_PATH]
            }, { test: /\.(svg)$/i,
                loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
                include: [
                    require.resolve('antd').replace(/warn\.js$/, '')
                // path.resolve(__dirname, 'images/'),  
                ]}
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: { 
            name: 'runtime' 
        },
        namedModules:true,
        namedChunks:true,
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'async', 
            minSize: 30000, 
            maxSize: 0, 
            minChunks: 1,
            maxAsyncRequests: 10,
            maxInitialRequests: 5,
            automaticNameDelimiter: '_',
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    priority: -10
                },
                default: {
                    test: src,
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -20,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                libs_draw2d: {
                    name: 'libs_draw2d',
                    test: path.resolve(src, 'libs', 'draw2d'),
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -8,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                libs_jqueryUI: {
                    name: 'libs_jquery_ui',
                    test: path.resolve(src, 'libs', 'jquery-ui'),
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -8,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                libs_echarts: {
                    name: 'libs_echarts',
                    test: /echarts/,
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -8,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                libs_antd: {
                    name: 'libs_antd',
                    test: /antd/,
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -8,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                libs_iconfont: {
                    name: 'libs_iconfont',
                    test: path.resolve(src, 'style', 'iconfont'),
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    priority: -8,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                node_commons: {
                    name: 'node_commons',
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -10,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                ecs_commons: {
                    name: 'ecs_commons',
                    test: path.resolve(src, 'common'),
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -10,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                ecs_basicobject: {
                    name: 'ecs_basicobject',
                    test: /basicobject[\\/]component[\\/][fields|common]/,
                    // minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -10,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                }
            }
        },
        usedExports: true 
    },
    plugins
};
```

I want to use webpack to concate some initial resources to get better load performance.
[image]

And I tried these configs to concate css files, and It's only concate two of three css files, and It generate a new tiny `fssc/js/255_a3f37b43beef351679ca.js` file too:

```
cacheGroups: {
    // 合并css
    styles: {
        name (module) {
            console.log(module.context);
            const match = module.context.match(/[\\/](.*).css/);
            if (!match) {
                return false;
            }
            const moduleName = match[1];
            return moduleName;
        },
        test: /\.css$/,
        chunks: 'all',
        enforce: true
    },
}
```

[image]

It would be better if I could only concate the css files because these js files are big already. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks.